# How do I deal with d3.json to get my InitialState in React/redux

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

Using React/Redux, I'm trying to get external data into my initial state with express. I'm used to work with D3 so I wanted to use d3.json with my reducer like this :

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/authors';

function cool() {
d3.json(url, function(data) {
dataset = data;
 });
}

  const authorData = (state = dataset, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'DATA_CHART_ALL':
        return action.data
      case 'DATA_CHART_FILTER':
        return action.data
          default:
            return state;
                }
              };

export default authorData;
```

Since D3.json is a callback function, my reducer is returned undefined. How do I deal with this ? Can I use something else than d3.json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function that will act as a dispatcher in redux:

```
// redux action using a dispatcher (think middleware)
export function cool(url) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return d3.json(url, response => {
            dispatch(setData(response))
        }
    }
}

// redux action
export function setData(data) {
 return {
        type: 'DATA_CHART_ALL',
        data
    }
}

const authorDataReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'DATA_CHART_ALL':
        return action.data
      case 'DATA_CHART_FILTER':
        return action.data
      default:
        return state;
    }
};

export authorDataReducer;
```

to use it:

call this at the beginning of your application:

```
store.dispatch(cool("MY_URL"));
```

Note that i'm not checking for error handling in the request

Comment: yep. Thanks. I've come up with the same solution. however I was wondering is there is any other solution...

Comment: I coming back to this because it doesn't work. I've this error `ncaught TypeError: (0 , _index2.default) is not a function` ... ?

Comment: hey DOMZE, I've open another questions which is express my problem better I think here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907458/how-should-i-use-redux-thunk-for-async-initial-state-react-redux/38911857#38911857). I've tried to open a JSbin but I can't make it work http://jsbin.com/xocopal/15/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: You can't use ES6 straight into the browser. You have to pack (transpile it use webpack or use a polyfill

Comment: You speaking about the jsbin ?