# How should I use "redux-thunk" for Async Initial state ? (react/redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

This question have already been ask several time, however I didn't really understand the answers I found. Using React/Redux, I'm trying to get async data into my initial state with express. Since I'm used to d3 one of my option was to use "d3.json"... but I would be happy to use something else if it's better. From a previous answers on the same topic I add the following code :

```
// redux action using a dispatcher (think middleware)
export function cool(url) {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return d3.json(url, response => {
            dispatch(setData(response))
        }
    }
}

// redux action
export function setData(data) {
 return {
        type: 'DATA_CHART_ALL',
        data
    }
}

const authorDataReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'DATA_CHART_ALL':
        return action.data
      case 'DATA_CHART_FILTER':
        return action.data
      default:
        return state;
    }
};

export authorDataReducer;
```

I didn't notice it at first, but from what I have understand recently, this code above is following more or less the `redux-thunk` pattern... so from there I tried to apply `redux-thunk` but I can't make anything work...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but I will try to answer as good as possible. 
Redux-thunk is a middleware that you use to dispatch async actions. You initialize it when the redux store is being created as such:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

For loading async data, you will need to dispatch an action even if it's for the initial state. If you are using react, you could to this when your highest order component has mounted.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchTodos } from '../action';
import TodoList from './TodoList';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchTodos();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TodoList
                todos={this.props.todos}
            />
        );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    todos: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    todos: state.todos
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
        fetchTodos: fetchTodos
    }
)(App);
```

this will trigger an action which could look like this

```
export const fetchTodos = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return fetch(url).then((response) => {
            disptach({
                 type: 'received_todos',
                 payload: {
                     response.json()
                 }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I didn't use d3 but [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). I guess any library is good as long as you are returning a Promise.

Comment: When I'm adding `{ fetchTodos: fetchTodos }` in my `connect` I've got the following error `finalMergeProps is not a function`

Comment: fetchTodos should be an action which you import. the `{ fetchTodos: fetchTodos }` in the connect is just a way of mapping an action to a prop so that you can call it like `this.props.fetchTodos` in your component

Comment: yeah I have imported it. Do I need to do anything with my reducers ? and when you say promise what do you mean ? thanks again !

Comment: [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is used to return data from async actions. I think you should read the the [redux doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) because they have a lot of info there and some good examples.